# Test throws RequestGuard::viaRemember() does not exist on second request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-airlock

I have a test that looks like so:

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->state('verified')->create();

$this->be($user);
$file = new UploadedFile(storage_path('testing/user.jpg'), 'user.jpg', 'image/jpeg');

$this->post('/account/missing-fields/upload', [
    'file' => $file
], ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'])->dump();
$this->post('/account/missing-fields/upload', [
    'file' => $file
], ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'])->dump();
```

```
{#2983
  +"token": "hHAY7vD8fOiW8mVU9OIlxVSJv5FzAq52e0coaFHKRC"
  +"extension": "jpg"
  +"mime": "image/jpeg"
}
{#3072
  +"message": "Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::viaRemember does not exist."
  +"exception": "BadMethodCallException"
  +"file": "/app/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php"
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the first request is successful, and returns a token, when I do the request a second time, Laravel is suddenly saying that the `viaRemember` method doesn't exist.

I have no clue why is shouldn't be working.

It should be noted that I can change the post requests, and the second will always fail like above.

Going through the framework, the error occurs within `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession`, where the first request has one `web` guard and the second for some reason has `web` and `airlock`.

[image]

Comment: Did you end up finding the answer?

Comment: I guess you should define the guard here. Probably the web guard: `$this->be($admin, guard: 'web')`